# Linux Mint 18.3 and genymotion

Tags: genymotion

installed genymotion along with oracle virtualbox on my linux mint 18.3 laptop.  Created a new virtual device.  when i start up the virtual device, the android screen comes up for few seconds and it closes itself.

Is there a way to fix this error?

TIA,

Thomas

Answer (score 0):

the issue was with the display driver.  Originally when i installed Linux mint 18.3 i guess the installer used nouveau driver.  i've changed to the nvidia-340 and it's working now.